# parsing pdf using php

Tags: php, parsing, pdf

I know this question has been asked several times. And i have checked all but none were giving satisfactory answers.

Some say TCPDF can parse but i searched on its site. nothing is given to read the pdf.
thn xpdf- xpdf is a utility which is to be installed on server and than run commands to extract the text.

I even searched FPDF but in that site also nothing is given about reading the pdf or any function related to readin in manual.

So do i have to use pdfbox and java bridge to extract text..? or is some folk can answer that it is possible using tcpdf.

what to prefer now...?

Comment: A PDF is just basically Postscript code. Unless the text is embedded in an image, you should be able to look at the raw postscript code and extract the text using basic file i/o and string operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the status is largely the same as it was: there are no PHP native implementations of a PDF parser. There are [command line alternatives](http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php) and I know that there are implementations in other languages (I personally use the Python library), but no native PHP ones.